# HeidiSQL, attach/register database in MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql, database-administration

How to attach (or register) an existing MSSQL database to a server Using HeidiSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do this with a query:

```
CREATE DATABASE [YourDB] ON ( FILENAME = N'd:\path\to\YourDB.mdf' ),( FILENAME = N'd:\path\to\YourDB_log.ldf' ) FOR ATTACH
```

or

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'YourDB', 
    @filename1 = 
N'd:\path\to\YourDB.mdf', 
    @filename2 = 
N'd:\path\to\YourDB_log.ldf';
```